# XCode force line wrapping

Tags: ios, xcode

I am looking for force line wrapping functionality in XCode.

I did check that we have settings under `Preferences->Text Editing->Check Page guide enable`. But what I want is while typing and formatting the code, all sentence should not exceeds this page guide limit.

I searched a lot, but could not able to find the desired solution. So basically I am looking for some settings of command which can forcefully wrap the exceeding lines. Please find the screenshots for better understanding of my question.

This is how page guide is enabled
[image: This is how page guide is enabled]

This is what I need
[image: This is what I need]

Answer (score 1):

You can set a page guide (in `Preferences -> Text Editing -> Editing`) to the width you want.  It will show up as a pale-grey vertical line in the code pane. Then you can pull the right-edge of the code pane to the left to match the line.  If line wrap is turned on, then the lines of code should wrap to that size.  It's clunky and not automatic, but it works.

Comment: It does work, ... but not for those windows like the main one where you hide and show parts like the utility area to the right. So, Apple, it would still make sense to support wrapping at page guide.